# problem using Hibernate annotation with JodaTime

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, jodatime

i am coming back because i still have problem using JodaTime. After the previous comments, i modified my pom and the **@Type annotation** is fixed. Here is my new pom :

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.6.0.Beta1</hibernate.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
     ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda Time dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am actually developping a personnal project where i use Spring and Hibernate. I also use JodaTime to persist the date fields. When i am doing unit testing with Junit4, i caught this exception :

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
  ....  
fr.cc2i.intervention.dao.test.WebInterventionTest.oneTimedSetUp(WebInterventionTest.java:33)
    .....
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at 
           .....
```

According to that website : http://www.mail-archive.com/joda-interest@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00609.html, jodatime might cause the error.

Can someone explain me what is : `java.lang.incompatibleChangeError : Implementing Class` ?
and how to solve that problem?

My spring configuration :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"> <ref local="dataSource" /></property> 
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>

            <!-- Pour les requetes SQL -->
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</prop>

            <!-- manipuler avec attention       -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>fr.cc2i.intervention.dao.beans.Client</value>
            <value>fr.cc2i.intervention.dao.beans.Intervention</value>
            <value>fr.cc2i.intervention.dao.beans.Technicien</value>
            <value>fr.cc2i.intervention.dao.beans.Contrat</value>               
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My entity class :

```
    package fr.cc2i.intervention.dao.beans;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.Period;

/**
 * Classe définissant un contrat
 * My code is written in French ;)
 * @author lindows
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="T_Contrat")
public class Contrat {

    private long id;

    private String reference;

    private Period heures_totales;

    private Period heures_restantes;


    public Contrat(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    @Column
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistantPeriod")
    public Period getHeures_totales() {
        return heures_totales;
    }

    public void setHeures_totales(Period heuresTotales) {
        heures_totales = heuresTotales;
    }

    @Column
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistantPeriod")
    public Period getHeures_restantes() {
        return heures_restantes;
    }

    public void setHeures_restantes(Period heuresRestantes) {
        heures_restantes = heuresRestantes;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.reference + " - \n Heures totales :" + this.heures_totales.toString() + 
         " Heures Restantes : " + this.heures_restantes.toString();
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should do some cleanup, your dependencies are a **huge** mess: you are mixing different versions of hibernate-core, hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-annotations (they are released together since 3.5), you have both JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0 API jars, you are using the JPA 1.0 version of hibernate-entitymanager, you are declaring many dependencies that you would get transitively like asm and javassist, etc. Remove all the above and just declare a dependency on hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.4-Final.jar, that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, your `pom.xml` is messy and this is somehow the root cause of the issue. Here comes the full explanation.

According to the announcement of the [Simultaneous Hibernate 3.5.4 and 3.6.0.Beta1 Releases](http://relation.to/Bloggers/SimultaneousHibernate354And360Beta1Releases) quoted below, the *hibernate-annotations* module has been **merged** into *core* in Hibernate 3.6.x (made possible since Hibernate 3.6.x is dropping JDK 1.4 support):

> #### [3.6.0.Beta1](http://relation.to/Bloggers/SimultaneousHibernate354And360Beta1Releases#H-360Beta1)
>
> 3.6 introduces some new features as well as incorporating most of the
>   fixes from 3.5. Changes of particular
>   interest include
>
> - Dropping support for JDK 1.4
> - **merging some modules into core; specifically hibernate-jmx and
>     hibernate-annotations**
> - repackaging of classes in hibernate-testing
> - [HHH-2277](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2277) : fixes a long known limitation in key-many-to-one support.
> - [HHH-5138](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5138), [HHH-5182](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5182), [HHH-5262](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5262) : collectively address a
>     number of improvements to the
>     "Hibernate type system". See the newly
>     separated and expanded chapter on
>     Types in the reference manual for
>     details.
> - [HHH-5268](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5268) : java.util.UUID support
>
> For more details about 3.6.0.Beta1,
>   including the full list of changes,
>   see the [release page](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH/fixforversion/10941).

And indeed, the latest versions of [`hibernate-annotations-3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar`](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.6.0-SNAPSHOT/) are actually **empty jars** (because of the merge) that were temporarily built until the total removal of the maven module itself. But because you're not using `hibernate-core-3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar`, you just don't have the `@Type` annotation at all.

Now, here is a summary of my recommendations/remarks:

- Use Maven transitive dependency resolution mechanism, do **not** declare all dependencies but only the "top level" one i.e. `hibernate-entitymanager` if you want to use JPA.
- Starting with version 3.5, Hibernate Core, Annotations, EntityManager are **released together**, their versions are in **sync**.
- If you want to use Hibernate 3.6.x (Beta2 is there now), the `@Type` is in `hibernate-core` (that's not really important if you use transitive dependencies).
- I don't recommend to rely on SNAPSHOT unless you know exactly what you're doing.

So your `pom.xml` should declare something like this for Hibernate:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <!--hibernate.version>3.4.O.GA</hibernate.version-->    <!-- for JPA 1.0 -->
    <hibernate.version>3.5.4-Final</hibernate.version>      <!-- for JPA 2.0 -->
    <!--hibernate.version>3.6.0.Beta2</hibernate.version--> <!-- experimental -->
  <properties>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...    
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

And that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Pascal, i made the correct changes and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Type` annotation is present in `hibernate-annotations`, version `3.5.1-Final`. I don't find the snapshot you are using 3.6.0-SNAPSHOT in the [jboss](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/) repository, so I couldn't test that specifically, but my guess is that the annotation is missing/has been removed from the snapshot version for some reason.

Unless there is a specific reason you need a snapshot, I would stick to released versions. If you revert to 3.5.1-Final, that will fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your answer. I finally switch to 3.5.5-SNAPSHOT version and it works. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The Type API is changing in Hibernate 3.6.0. I would be surprised if the Joda Time Contrib classes work at all with Hibernate 3.6 although they should work with Hibernate 3.5. Can I suggest you take a look at my project which has implementations of Usertypes for Joda Time and JSR310: http://usertype.sourceforge.net/

Thanks and regards,

Chris